# Proving monotonicity of a sequence $x_{n} = \frac{1-n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to prove whether this sequence is monotone

### **$x_{n} = \frac{1-n}{\sqrt{n}}$**

I've got that $x_{n} = \frac{1-n}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{n}$ and the limit of it approaches $-\infty$ when n approaches $\infty$

I know there's such a theorem about monotone sequence, which tells that if decreasing sequence is bounded, then it's convergent, otherwise it approaches  $-\infty$. As we can see, this sequence is divergent.

So the question is.
Can we tell that this sequence is monotone decreasing, because it is divergent which approaches $-\infty$?

I know that I should have proven this like $x_n \geq x_{n+1}$ for all n from N \ {0}, but I'm having some troubles with simplifications because of my limited math background.I have tried either subtraction, division and Stolz theorem with no luck. Please provide some directions, thank you.

Comment: As for whether we can say a sequence is no time decreasing because it approaches $-\infty$ the answer is no. Consider the sequence $$a_n = \begin{cases} 0 & n = 5 \\ -n & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$.

Comment: ahh, now I see the point.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't tell.There are are lots of sequences that tend to $-\infty$ without being monotonic.

It is decreasing because it is the sum of the decreasing sequences $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $-\sqrt {n}$.

Comment: ... which are each decreasing because $\sqrt{n}$ is an increasing sequence

Comment: That goes without saying…

Answer (score 3):

$$x_n\ge x_{n+1}\iff \frac{1-n}{\sqrt n}\ge\frac{1-(n+1)}{\sqrt{n+1}}\iff (1-n)\sqrt{n+1}\ge -n\sqrt n\iff$$

$$\iff (n-1)\sqrt{n+1}\le n\sqrt n\iff (n-1)^2(n+1)\le n^3\iff$$

$$\iff n^3-n^2-n+1\le n^3\iff -(n^2+n-1)\le 0$$

and the last inequality is in fact true for all $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$

Comment: Thanks, seems pretty intuitive, but how do I know the inequality sign at first stage to continue?

Comment: @shcolf An educated guess...or else I leave a $\;\le\ge\;$ sign all the way long until I reach an obvious inequality...if at all. If my guess turns to be wrong I just change all the signs.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another idea, let $f(x)=x^{-\frac12}-x^{\frac12}$, then $f'(x)=-\frac{x+1}{2x^{3/2}}$, which is clearly $<0$ when $x>0$.

Comment: Thank you. This gotta be the easiest solution maybe. I'm just trying to avoid using derivitive, as I'm still studying basics of analysis so "can't" do proofs like this

Comment: @Tim, how do you define $\;x^{3/2}\;$ negative values of $\;x\;$ ?? Even more interesting, you $\;f(x)\;$ is **not** defined (as a real function) for negative values (not even for zero)

Comment: Once again, derivative is not require to see it's decreasing.

Comment: @Bernard You're right. In fact, I think your solution is the best.  I was just pointing out that the derivative is a tool that can be used in these situations.

Comment: @Timbuc It's not necessary to define $x^{3/2}$ for $x<0$, since we are only interested in the values of $f'$ for positive $x$.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski You are right. Thank you.